# How to display a message after drop every element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display a message after drop each element.

For that I have written code in jQuery like this:

```JS
if($(this).find('ol .placeholder').length > 0)
{
    isAllFilled = false;
    return
}

if(isAllFilled)
{
    alert('All Boxes have elements.');
    $("#equal").show();
    $("#equal a").html("CONGRATULATION ! YOU HAVE ENTERED APPROPRIATE BLOCKS FOR ACCOUNTING.");
}
```

Here you can check my code - http://jsfiddle.net/sanjayrathod7/5cZD5/20/

But I think something is wrong with my code.

Please look into my code and tell me where I am making mistake.

Please help.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question, what you exactly looking for?

Comment: in jsfiddle we can drag and drop four element. after drop this four element message should be display - CONGRATULATION ! YOU HAVE ENTERED APPROPRIATE BLOCKS FOR ACCOUNTING

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
if($(this).find('ol .placeholder2').length > 0)
        {
            isAllFilled = false;
            return
        }

               });

    if(isAllFilled)
    {
      alert('All Boxes have elements.');
         $("#equal").show();
         $("#equal a").html("CONGRATULATION ! YOU HAVE ENTERED APPROPRIATE BLOCKS FOR ACCOUNTING.");
    }
}
```